# Is there a CSS bug in jQueryUI icons

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-ui, css-float

i used the markup used this page [jQueryUI Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) the one with `ui-state-error` css class at the bottom right sidebar. the markup goes like below

```
<div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all"> 
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span> 
<strong>Alert:</strong> Sample ui-state-error style.</p>
</div>
```

but to my surprise it doesn't look the same , the icon falls on it's own line [possibly because it's display is `blocked`]. Now is this a known css bug or Intended. If so what would my possible solution be, float these `ui-icon` elements left all the time ??

I couldn't put that on jsfiddle but JsBin did work here is the link [Edit the Example on JsBin](http://jsbin.com/agagep/2)

Comment: Throw your code on jsfiddle so we can take a look.

Comment: @Babak added link to jsbin for editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make the icon stay in the middle of text try adding

```
.ui-icon-fix-by-max
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Comment: i would doubt the validity of `inline-block` when working cross browser

Comment: you backed your answer with another , sure solves the problem for now but this isn't permanent solution. I am going to ask the filament group about this

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug from what I know, the way I have done it is like this: http://jsbin.com/agagep/5/ (did the css with jquery but actually have something like that in a css file), even if we want this to be like this it doesn't mean that everyone wants it, it lets the designer have more control over what is happening.

Comment: i voted you up, because with javascript disabled it wouldn't work but max4ever's solution will because of CSS solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a bug in the jquery ui theme. But I know they don't really look great like if they were not finished. You can have a look at this awesome theme for jquery ui theme : http://www.warfuric.com/taitems/demo.html and download here https://github.com/taitems/Aristo-jQuery-UI-Theme

Don't really answer the question but maybe can be useful to you.